# Using sed to add character in a line which contains TWO specific Strings

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, sed

I want to do something like this:

```
sed "/^[^+]/ s/\(.*$1|$2.*$\)/+\ \1/" -i file
```

where 2 specific String Parameters are being checked in a file and in those lines where BOTH parameters ($1 | $2) occur, a + is added at the beginning of the line if there was no + before.

Tried different variations so far and ending up either checking both but then sed'ing every line that contains 1 of the 2 Strings or some errors.
Thankful for any clarifications regarding slash and backslash escaping (respectively single/double quotes) i guess thats where my problem lies.

Edit: Wished outcome: (Folder containing bunch of text files one of which has the following 2 lines)

```
sudo bash MyScript.sh 01234567 Wanted
```

Before:

```
Some Random Text And A Number 01234567 and i'm Wanted.
Another Random Text with Diff Number 09812387 and i'm still Wanted.
```

Expected:

```
+ Some Random Text And A Number 01234567 and i'm Wanted.
Another Random Text with Diff Number 09812387 and i'm still Wanted.
```

Comment: Can you add example input? What characters can be in `$1` or `$2`?

Comment: a number like 00932170 or a word for instance: WorldHello

Comment: Please add example input and the expected output so people can test their solutions.

Comment: Like i said, its a mixture of numbers (signature) and words that will be looked for (each time different): sudo bash sedscript.sh "01234567" "Wanted"
output is in a textfile which would look like this afterwards:
+ this_is some random Text, my Phone number is not 01234567, im havent seen the movie Wanted.

Comment: It's easier to read if you [edit] the question instead of add data in the comments.

Comment: Do you want to insert `+` or `+_`? Or `+` with a blank?

Comment: @BenjaminW. + with a blank. the formation wanted to add a "•" bc i didnt have it in code format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an input file that looks as follows:

```
$ cat infile
Some Random Text And A Number 01234567 and i'm Wanted.
Another Random Text with Diff Number 09812387 and i'm still Wanted.
```

and setting `$1` and `$2` to `01234567` and `Wanted` (in a script, these are just the first two positional parameters and don't have to be set):

```
$ set -- 01234567 Wanted
```

the following command would work:

```
$ sed '/^+/b; /'"$1"'/!b; /'"$2"'/s/^/+ /' infile
+ Some Random Text And A Number 01234567 and i'm Wanted.
Another Random Text with Diff Number 09812387 and i'm still Wanted.
```

This is how it works:

```
sed '
    /^+/b           # Skip if line starts with "+"
    /'"$1"'/!b      # Skip if line doesn't contain first parameter
    /'"$2"'/s/^/+ / # Prepend "+ " if second parameter is matched
' infile
```

`b` is the "branch" command; when used on its own (as opposed to with a label to jump to), it skips all commands.

The first two commands skip lines that start with `+` or that don' t contain the first parameter; if we're on the line with the `s` command, we already know that the current line doesn't start with `+` and contains the first parameter. If it contains the second parameter, we prepend `+` .

For quoting, I have single quoted the whole command except for where the parameters are included:

```
'single quoted'"$parameter"'single quoted'
```

so I don't have to escape anything unusual. This assumes that the variable in the double quoted part doesn't contain any metacharacters that might confuse sed.

Comment: are ";" and ":" metacharacters that could lead to problems? will be checking everything else tomorrow, looks like it could be working

Comment: @greg `:` and `;` shouldn't confuse sed.